# select SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Sorry I'm new to the SQL Server world

this the checktime table

```
select * from CHECKINOUT where USERID= 467
 and CHECKTIME>'2014-10-24 00:00:00:000' order by CHECKTIME





  useid   checktime
    467 2014-10-24 02:18:20.000
    467 2014-10-24 17:04:43.000
    467 2014-10-25 02:31:40.000
    467 2014-10-25 17:13:38.000
    467 2014-10-25 20:59:10.000
    467 2014-10-27 17:22:06.000
    467 2014-10-28 02:55:57.000
    467 2014-10-28 17:57:12.000
    467 2014-10-29 02:36:30.000
    467 2014-10-29 17:13:35.000
    467 2014-10-30 02:35:47.000
    467 2014-10-30 17:17:56.000
    467 2014-10-31 03:02:50.000
    467 2014-10-31 17:19:18.000
    467 2014-11-01 02:42:18.000
    467 2014-11-01 17:16:14.000
    467 2014-11-02 02:44:00.000
    467 2014-11-03 17:20:10.000
    467 2014-11-04 02:38:57.000
    467 2014-11-05 02:15:50.000
    467 2014-11-05 17:14:25.000

and i need the output like



 useid      checkin                    checkout
    467     2014-10-24 17:04:43.000   2014-10-25 02:31:40.000   
    467     2014-10-27 17:22:06.000   2014-10-28 02:55:57.000   
    467     2014-10-28 17:57:12.000   2014-10-29 02:36:30.000
```

and if there is no check out like 2014-11-05 17:14:25.000  put checkout null tanks for help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you please show us the table structure (what columns with what datatypes) and some sample data, and then explain what you're trying to do with that data (what output you're trying to achieve)

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code `AND Checkin = DATEPART(hh,[CHECKTIME]) >= 17` this is not possible. Explain what you are trying to achieve using this code.

Comment: checkin and checkout is not column name its checktime as checkin and checktime as checkout –

Comment: This date `2014-10-27 17:22:06.000` is not present in table. then how come it got into output

Comment: Is there any other column which indicates `CheckIn` or `CheckOut`

Comment: Mr @Pradeepn  no checkin or checkout column it as checkin or as checkout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64547/discussion-between-new-user-and-pradeep).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your issues is, I think this will get you what you need.

```
 SELECT USERID, MIN(CHECKTIME) AS Checkin, MAX(CHECKTIME) AS Checkout
 FROM checkinout
 WHERE [CHECKTIME] > '2014-10-24' 
 AND DATEPART(hh,MIN(CHECKTIME)) >= '17'
 AND DATEPART(hh,MIN(CHECKTIME)) <= '22'
 AND DATEPART(hh,MAX(CHECKTIME)) >= '17' 
 AND DATEPART(hh,MAX(CHECKTIME)) <= '22'      
 AND USERID = '467'
 ORDER BY Checkin
```

And if you want it for all users not just 467

```
 SELECT USERID, MIN(CHECKTIME) AS Checkin, MAX(CHECKTIME) AS Checkout
 FROM checkinout
 WHERE [CHECKTIME] > '2014-10-24' 
 AND DATEPART(hh,MIN(CHECKTIME)) >= '17'
 AND DATEPART(hh,MIN(CHECKTIME)) <= '22'
 AND DATEPART(hh,MAX(CHECKTIME)) >= '17' 
 AND DATEPART(hh,MAX(CHECKTIME)) <= '22'      
 GROUP BY CHECKTIME, USERID
 ORDER BY Checkin
```

Comment: min and max give me the answer from the same date and this statement to finger print for night shift chick in from 17:00:00 to 22:00:00 and check out in the next date between 1:00:00 and 4:00:00

Comment: and checkin and checkout is not column name  its checktime as checkin  and checktime as checkout

Comment: Even now first query wont compile dude!!

Comment: In first query select has 3 columns in which `USERID` is not wrapped inside an `aggregate` so where is the `group by`

Comment: @Pradeep this table its for finger print machine and this user have shift between 5 pm to 2 am and what i need is to have check in and check out from table checkinout thats all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USERID,MIN(checktime) AS InTime,MAX(checktime) AS OutTime
    FROM checkinout
where USERID=467 and CHECKTIME>'2014-10-24 00:00:00.000'
       GROUP BY USERID,DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime)) 
    HAVING MIN(checktime) <> MAX(checktime)
    AND MAX(DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime))-DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime)) > '22:00' 
    ORDER BY MIN(checktime)
```